# C implementation of filter with Matlab generated coefficients

Tags: c, signal-processing

First off, this is intended as some research for a future application.

I want to be able to extract the coefficients from a c header file that is generated by the Matlab Filter Design and Analysis Tool (FDATool).

[fdatool settings http://dl.dropbox.com/u/39710897/fdatool.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/39710897/fdatool.png)

I have used the above settings for the FDATool and then I generated the following C header file:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/39710897/fdacoefs.h

As I understand it I can implement a filter from this by using a direct form difference equation. 
I believe the equation to be y(n) = b<sub>0</sub>x(n) + b<sub>1</sub>x(n–1) + b<sub>2</sub>x(n–2) – a<sub>1</sub>y(n–1) – a<sub>2</sub>y(n–2)

where the b<sub>0</sub>-b<sub>2</sub> coefficients are the zeroes and the a<sub>1</sub> and a<sub>2</sub> coefficients are the poles.

The problem here is that I'm not entirely sure what is in the header file. This information seems surprisingly hard to find which probably means I'm missing something really obvious...

Here is the information I think I've been able to extract:

- Filter is made up from 3 biquadratic (known as "biquad") sections.
- The coefficients for section 1 are:

  - b0:0.129355475306511
  - b1:-1.997004866600037
  - b2:1.000000000000000
  - a1:-1.995552659034729
  - a2:0.996141731739044
- The coefficients for section 2 are:

  - b0:0.129355475306511
  - b1:-1.999969959259033
  - b2:1.000000000000000
  - a1:-1.997882604598999
  - a2:0.998035132884979
- The coefficients for section 3 are:

  - b0:0.011426069773734
  - b1:0.000000000000000
  - b2:-1.000000000000000
  - a1:-1.993502736091614
  - a2:0.993802070617676

Questions:

1. Is my difference equation suitable for use with the coefficients in the header file?
2. Is the information I extracted from the header file correct?

Comment: I have this distinct feeling I'm almost right on top of the solution, but I somehow can't see it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the screen shot you appear to be using Direct Form **II** biquad sections (aka Canonical Form) - see Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_biquad_filter and note the difference equations for Direct Form II (you seem to be using the difference equation for Direct Form I above).

[image]

[image]

Note that the w terms are not labelled on the diagram on the Wikipedia page but they are the delayed terms in the middle.

Comment: this seems to have been the problem... can't quite believe I missed something that obvious..